# React native app rapidly consumes memory?

Tags: react-native

I've started to fiddle around with React Native, I followed the directions on the start page exactly. After initiating a new project I opened up the file in xcode and the build succeeded. The test application, which is just a view and some lines of text, seems to rapidly consume memory. After letting it run for 5 minutes it's at 284.5mb of memory used and climbing. This seems wrong. Is there a memory leak here? If so, what could be causing it or how could I track down what the cause is?

I'm using react native version 0.17.

Comment: Maybe release costs fewer memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no RN version 0.1.7... there is 0.17.0 coming though. You might be seeing the memory leak originally reported in 0.15.0 which should be fixed in the upcoming version 0.17.0. See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4538